# Free web hosting with python script

Tags: web-hosting, python

I plan to display my Python script run result to share with others. thus, I plan to do a android apps and also a websites. I have use Pythonanywhere to run my python script and send my result to MYSQL. Unfortunately free account has its limitation.
I plan to host in free web hosting in long term. I found heliohost but I am unsure if it is suitable for my requirements. I need a python script taht can run everyday at a certain time and save the output to MySQL so that people can access from android apps or webs.
Besides, hekiohost, any web hosting that I can run python script fro free and allow higher bandwidth and storage? There are some free web hosting with large storage but does not disclosed if I can run my Python script. 
Thanks in advance